# Video with multiple audio tracks

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, video-streaming

I want to make a web page where I display a video with options of multiple audio tracks where user can switch between different tracks available and just the audio will switch or maybe if possible video goes back 10 seconds and continues with selected audio track (eg. VLC player where we can select between different tracks).

How should i go about it? I read about VideoJs but couldn't understand how to do it.

Comment: suggest you have a quick look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand why there's a 'close' flag here, but to get you started have a look at example #2 here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_the_track_element_to_provide_audio_descriptions which seems to address what you're trying to do...

Comment: This might help also: https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-audio-tracks.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add audio tracks through HTML like you can with text tracks. They must be added programmatically.
Video.js only stores track representations. Switching audio tracks for playback is not handled by Video.js and must be handled elsewhere - for example, videojs-contrib-hls handles switching audio tracks to support track selection through the UI.

Reference: https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-audio-tracks.html